# Umbraco Razor code in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, razor, umbraco

I'm using Umbraco 7.2.2, to create my new website. Everything works great and all on the site, with the code or what not, but in my Visual Studio Editor, when I for example open a Template Page, I get errors under the razor-code, saying that the type or namespace could not be found, but again, it works on the actual pages.

I was wondering what is causing this problem, and hopefully a solution to it? Coding with IDE errors is not something I'd like to do :D

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio requires that the dlls you are referencing are copied locally in the bin folder of your project, in order to avoid that kind of Razor warning. In particular check that umbraco.dll is referenced with **Local Copy = true**